# How to get last nth element of linkedlist in java

Tags: java

Guys how can we access last element of linkedlist.

Assume that one linkedlist defined like

1->2->5->7->9->10

now i want to access last 3rd element .

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: If it is doubly, use an iterator and start from the tail...

Comment: take a look at the get method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#get(int)

Comment: you should iterate from head pointer 2 times.

Comment: Why don't you simply use methods `size` and `get`? Any problems?

Answer (score 1):

```
int numberFromEnd = 3;
list.get(list.size() - (numberFromEnd + 1));
```